# Entity Framework user select database target

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So here is my question. For my open source project it is essential that we allow the user to store the contents of the cache on the file system, we currently do this by serializing the cache into json and store it as plain text files.
Since we want to get away from this solution in future versions, we are now looking for way to store the cache in a database.
In our current plans the user has the possibility to decide which database he wants to use (e.g. SQL Server compact, an already existing database, etc.). Now my questions are:

1. Can something like this be achieved with EF? Can I switch the database while the application is running, or do I need to recompile the application for a database switch?
2. Would EF be the best way to do this, or am I overlooking better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

```
Can something like this be achieved with EF? Can I switch the database while the application is running, or do I need to recompile the application for a database switch?
```

If you have different database like Oracle, MS SQL etc, then in EF you have to make different models for each of them and then distribute to the client depend on which database they are using.

```
Would EF be the best way to do this, or am I overlooking better solutions?
```

It totally depends, you can possibly achieve this by simple ado.net. But for sake of flexibility EF code first and T4 code generator from model gives you nice options in which your domain data , data access layer, bussiness rule will be same for different database. You just have to modify the connection in app. config file.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: So meaning, if the user generates the database structure himself, we just could modify the connection string in the app.config file and be done with it?

Comment: if its for same database like MS SQL to MS SQL, syntax of constructor in C# "public context : base("cnn name") remain same. But if its for MS SQL to Oracle syntax in C# constructor also changed like "public context() : base(new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cnn name"].ConnectionString)).